# Google Maps in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to get Google Maps into my application from within Android Studio. I found a tutorial which suggested openning up my .grade file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
} 
apply plugin: 'android'
```

and add this line to dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'
```

I added this line and my .grade file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

When I added this line, and tried to rebuild my project I get this error:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'BeerPortfolioPro'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25]
  Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)
```

Update:

I tried changing my .grade from one of the answers below to this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

and now I get this error:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'BeerPortfolioPro'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30.
        Required by:
            :BeerPortfolioPro:unspecified
```

Comment: Side Note: If you don't plan on supporting Froyo or Gingerbread (API 8 through 10) then consider changing your minimum supported version to 15. There is only 0.1% of Honeycomb devices active, and a negligible amount between 12,13 and 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your SDK Manager and install/update the Android Support Repository, Android Support Library v19, Google Repository and Google Play Service v13.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar "No signature of method" error, and realised that I'd added the dependency to the wrong file. When creating my project, Android Studio created 2 build.gradle files, one in the project root directory (alongside local.properties and gradle.properties), and one in a subdirectory named after my app (alongside the src and build directories). The play-services dependency needs to be added to the latter of these files, not the former.

Answer (score 0):

The `dependencies` block in your `buildscript` section is for including files required for the gradle build script. Google Play Services should be in the "app" `dependencies' section.

Here's a suggestion buildscript solution.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

android {
     compileSdkVersion 19
     buildToolsVersion "19"

     defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
     }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}
```

**Extra Notes**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
```

This will make sure you have the latest gradle 6 build tools.

Also the following block will make sure you're using the latest SDK version and build tools, while still including SDK 11 as the minimum supported version. Build Tools v19.0.0 has improvements over previous versions, but also plays nicely with Java 7.

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

If you cannot reference play-service 4 then a temporary solution could be to reference play-services:3.2.25 as specified in the documentation. A better solution would be to upload the library to your own maven repository (like [Sonatype Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/go)) and pull the dependency from there.

Comment: tried your suggestion but now I get this error on rebuild:

Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'BeerPortfolioPro'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0.
        Required by:
            :BeerPortfolioPro:unspecified
      > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30.
        Required by:
            :BeerPortfolioPro:unspecified

Comment: If you cannot reference play-service 4 then a temporary solution could be to reference play-services:3.2.25 as specified in the documentation. A better solution would be to upload the library to your own maven repository (like Sonatype Nexus) and pull the dependency from there.

This same solution applies to the support library. Also, don't include the support library if you don't need it.

Comment: To solve the problem with not being able to find the libraries, open your SDK Manager and install the Android Support Repository and Google Repository.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `minSdkVersion` problem. Change it to 14, for Android 4.0.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```